# Return record where frequency count does not match

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset in R, where WO can have values "K" and "B". I want to have the WO be returned where the frequency per WO does not match between the "K" and "B" records. For example the following table:

[image: See table]

```
df <- structure(list(WO = c(917595L, 917595L, 1011033L, 1011033L), 
    Invoice = c("B", "K", "B", "K"), freq = c(3L, 6L, 2L, 2L)),
    .Names = c("WO", "Invoice", "freq"),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)
)
```

I want 917595 returned because 3 does not equal 6. However, 1011033 should be returned because its frequency matches.

Comment: 917595's frequency differs between the K,B-records: do you want it returned or not returned? But you say you want 1011033 returned because its frequency *does* match. I am confussed...

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping the data let's you do a comparison on the frequency values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

dframe <- 
  "WO,Invoice,freq
917595,B,3
917595,K,6
1011033,B,2
1011033,K,2" %>% 
  read.csv(text = .,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

  dcast(dframe,
        WO ~ Invoice,
        value.var = "freq") %>% 
  filter(B != K)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have about 60,000 records and have it as a data frame, would the above code work the same? Thank you.

Comment: If the data are in the same structure as the sample data you offered, I don't see it being a problem.

Comment: My values being returned are not giving me the WO. I first though it was the indices but it is not.

Comment: check the class of `WO`.  Is it a `factor` by chance?

Comment: It is a factor. What class does it need to be?

Comment: You will want it to be character, otherwise you may find times that the factor gets converted to its underlying integer value.  Before doing `dcast`, use `as.character(dframe$WO)`.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not getting it. I did what you advised.  However, when I do not filter it, it lists the WO values, but once I filter it, I do not get the WO values.

Comment: do you have a `WO` column when you run my code above?

Comment: Yes. I was able to turn my reformatted data into another data frame then make a subset based upon the same condition in the filter part. It worked! Thank you so much for letting me know about the necessity of reshaping my data!

Answer (score 0):

We could do it with `base R` using `duplicated`

```
df1[!(duplicated(df1[c(1, 3)])|duplicated(df1[c(1,3)], fromLast = TRUE)),]
#      WO Invoice freq
#1 917595       B    3
#2 917595       K    6
```

---

Or another option is to group by 'WO' and check `if` the number of `unique` elements in 'freq' is greater than 1

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(freq)>1) .SD, WO]
#       WO Invoice freq
#1: 917595       B    3
#2: 917595       K    6
```